# Waiting tasks in TPL and disturbing issue with QueuedTaskScheduler (from ParallelExtensionsExtra)

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm facing a disturbing issue with the QueuedTaskScheduler that is ship with the ParallelExetensionExtras, but my question is rather general about waiting tasks, task schedulers and thread resources.

It seems that waiting tasks consume resource, check this example first that uses the default task scheduler, in this example there is one tasks that runs for a long time and several tasks that wait for its completion, while there are other tasks that are pending execution below.

Everything works well here, i can see that those waiting tasks start their work, and then free their resources during the wait period such that the other tasks start their execution as well.

```
var taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;//ts.ActivateNewQueue(0);

var longRunningTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(Int32.MaxValue), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi from waiting task");
    longRunningTask.Wait();
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi from waiting task");
    longRunningTask.Wait();
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi from waiting task");
    longRunningTask.Wait();
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler);
```

If i change the first two lines to do this:

```
var ts = new QueuedTaskScheduler();
var taskScheduler = ts.ActivateNewQueue(0);
```

meaning, define a QueuedTaskScheduler with one queue and run the same code, the other tasks just never get resources to run.

My question is if anyone bumped into it before and if anyone knows how can i change a task scheduler to free resources for waiting tasks.

Comment: Why exactly are those tasks waiting for the first `Task`?

Answer (score 0):

The `QueuedTaskScheduler` is behaving as designed. The problem is that it has a fixed maximum concurrency level, by default set to `Environment.ProcessorCount`.

Because of this, there will be at most 4 running tasks on it on a 4-core computer, assuming you didn't change the default.

To fix this, you can either run the long running task on a different scheduler (ideally one that supports `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`, like the `Default` one), or just set the maximum concurrency level, in extreme case to the max value:

```
var ts = new QueuedTaskScheduler(TaskScheduler.Default, int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: Hi, is it by design that waiting tasks would consume resources? Why isn't this the behavior in the default task scheduler?

Comment: I was testing the same code (with the long running task) on the default task scheduler and it worked just fine. What is the difference in the custom task schedulers that causes it to behave differently?

Comment: Oh and one more comment, max concurrency level defines how many threads are allocated, too many threads is not a solution - actually it is more likely to slow things down rather than speeding them up. Setting it to int.MaxValue will result in an OutOfMemoryException - and i wouldn't recommend it to anyone i guess.

Comment: Why do you think it's because waiting tasks consume resources? Like I said, the problem is the maximum concurrency level, the default task scheduler just have it set (its `MaximumConcurrencyLevel` returns `int.MaxValue`).

Comment: Ans whether increasing the concurrency level makes things faster or slower depends on what tasks are you running. If your tasks are often blocking, then the solution is either to not make them not block or increase the concurrency level.

Comment: Also, setting it to `int.MaxValue` won't cause OOM, at least not right away. Although it might mean you get OOM sooner than you would otherwise.